# javascript color randomizer does not work

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change the color of the circles every time I refresh the page

JavaScript code:

```
var colors = ['#ff0000', '#00ff00', '#0000ff'];
var random_color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
document.getElementById('cirkel1').style.background = random_color;
```

CSS code:

```
div {display: inline-block; margin-left: 10px;}

#cirkel1 { width: 100px; height: 100px; background: red; -moz-border-radius: 50px; -webkit-border-radius: 50px; border-radius: 50px; }

#cirkel2 { width: 100px; height: 100px; background: red; -moz-border-radius: 50px; -webkit-border-radius: 50px; border-radius: 50px; }

#cirkel3 { width: 100px; height: 100px; background: red; -moz-border-radius: 50px; -webkit-border-radius: 50px; border-radius: 50px; }

#cirkel4 { width: 100px; height: 100px; background: red; -moz-border-radius: 50px; -webkit-border-radius: 50px; border-radius: 50px; }
```

and HTML code:

```
<div id='cirkel'>
    <div id="cirkel1"></div>
    <div id='cirkel2'></div>
    <div id='cirkel3'></div>
    <div id='cirkel4'></div>
</div>
```

but for some reason it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I think its the width and height of the div. The color is changed but because div doesnt have width and height, you cant see the color.

Comment: @HarryBomrah The width and height are defined for every circle individually.

Comment: You are only changing the color of the first circle.

Comment: have you check my answer ?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not working because   `var random_color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];`

give you one color at a time and and store it in `random_color` to get random color for or every circle you need to call it whenever you need a new random color

please read comment in my code for understand how it is working

```js
var colors = ['#ff0000', '#00ff00', '#0000ff'];
var random_color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
//document.getElementById('cirkel1').style.background = random_color;
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("cir"); // read all circle by class name 
for(var i=0;i<x.length;i++ ){
// loop through every circle and every time generate a new random color 
 x[i].style.background = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
    console.log( x[i])
}
```

```css
div {display: inline-block; margin-left: 10px;}

    #cirkel1 { width: 100px; height: 100px; background: red; -moz-border-radius: 50px; -webkit-border-radius: 50px; border-radius: 50px; }

    #cirkel2 { width: 100px; height: 100px; background: red; -moz-border-radius: 50px; -webkit-border-radius: 50px; border-radius: 50px; }

    #cirkel3 { width: 100px; height: 100px; background: red; -moz-border-radius: 50px; -webkit-border-radius: 50px; border-radius: 50px; }

    #cirkel4 { width: 100px; height: 100px; background: red; -moz-border-radius: 50px; -webkit-border-radius: 50px; border-radius: 50px; }
```

```html
<div id='cirkel'>
    <div id="cirkel1" class="cir"></div>
    <div id='cirkel2' class="cir"></div>
    <div id='cirkel3' class="cir"></div>
    <div id='cirkel4' class="cir" ></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you leave out the `class="cir"` on the last circle for a reason?

Comment: no i just didn't see it , i have updated that, thanks for pointing

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a random number generator function and call it each time.

```
var randomNumber = function(){
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)
}
```

then

```
document.getElementById('cirkel1').style.backgroundColor = color[randomNumber()];
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/g17eLoer/)

Comment: I don't see how this changes anything. You just make a shortcut to get a random number. The result will be the same.

Comment: Wrong. He created one random_color variable that will be used on every element. When does he update the color for the next element?

Comment: You got a point. Though, he never sets the next element at all.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, but you are only updating the first circle.

```
document.getElementById('cirkel1').style.background = random_color;
```

If I change the code to:

```
var colors = ['#ff0000', '#00ff00', '#0000ff'];
function randomColor(){
    return colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
}
document.getElementById('cirkel1').style.background = randomColor();
document.getElementById('cirkel2').style.background = randomColor();
document.getElementById('cirkel3').style.background = randomColor();
document.getElementById('cirkel4').style.background = randomColor();
```

I get different colours.

This changes the random_colour to be a function.

Here is the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kgjertsen/mf7myuxs/